# Jquery animation - animating text shadow css on hover to achieve a slow effect from a blurred to a crisp text

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The title says all but I'll be more specific and detailed. It's 3 weeks that I'm trying to achieve this effect but it's not so easy as it sounds, and it starts to be frustrating.

I want animate text shadow on hover to achieve a slow effect from a blurred to a crisp text.

So, I want to animate the text shadow property of css with the jquery animate() function; I'd like to have it blurred when your enter the page; for instance like

//css

```
.blur{color: transparent; text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #000}
```

so with css would be easy to have it crisp on hover;

//css

```
.blur:hover{color: transparent; text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000}
```

but how can it make it slowing go to blur to crisp ?

I've found many examples on the web, but none is working like i want. Now this is the actual code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fx.step.textShadowBlur = function(fx){
$(fx.elem).css({'text-shadow': '0px 0px' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px #000'});
};

$('.blur').hover(function(){
$(this).animate({ textShadowBlur: '10px'}, console.log('antani'), 1000);
});

});
```

I've created a virtual property of the css because I know that jquery doesnt support text shadow has it is a multiple variable property.

I've also tried jquery css hook by Brian Aaron that can be found here:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/textshadow.js

no luck.

Please help me if you can :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, all of the browsers supporting text-shadow support css transitions in theirs most recent versions (Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox). Haven't tested it yet but you should be albe to animate text-shadow with it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried your method; it works: http://www.dimitrinube.com/work/francescovanstraten/ as you can see here. anyways it works well in safari, chrome, but i have to update to the latest version of firefox ( 4 ) to make it work there. maybe with jquery i can have a stronger support ? also, firefox handles blur differently than other browers: radius looks bigger.

Comment: You may find this [article on css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/) iteresting. It shows funny stuff with text shadow animations, one of them is animating radius using jquery csshooks and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is what you are looking for: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BlurMenu/index5.html